# Maximum shear stress contour plot

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math

I'm trying to plot shear stress on a half space with below formulation:

[image]

If we choose $a=1$, $p(s)=1$ and $t(s)=1$ we have:

$\sigma_x=-\frac{2y}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x-s)^2}{[(x-s)^2+y^2]^2}ds-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x-s)^3}{[(x-s)^2+y^2]^2}ds $

$\sigma_y=-\frac{2y^3}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{[(x-s)^2+y^2]^2}ds-\frac{2Y^2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x-s)}{[(x-s)^2+y^2]^2}ds $

I want to plot maximum shear stress:

$\tau_{max}=\frac{1}{2}|\sigma_x-\sigma_y|=C$

In which C is a positive variable

And I have written this code so far and got nothing:

```
syms x y s

sigmax(x,y,s)= int((-2*y/pi*(x-s)^2-2/pi*(x-s)^3)/((x-s)^2+y^2)^2,s);
SIGMAX(x,y)=sigmax(x,y,1)-sigmax(x,y,-1);
sigmay(x,y,s)= int((-2*y^3/pi-2/pi*y^2*(x-s))/((x-s)^2+y^2)^2,s);
SIGMAY(x,y)=sigmay(x,y,1)-sigmay(x,y,-1);
Taumax(x,y)=1/2*abs(SIGMAX(x,y)-SIGMAY(x,y));

ezplot(Taumax)
```

Is there any better way to plot symbolic result?

Comment: I want to plot this diagram for different values of C to get a contour.

Comment: My code shows nothing.

Comment: You can try to sample your symbolic expression at discrete points and plot those.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: You can use [`subs`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) to evaluate your function at a specific point.

Comment: I'm sorry for comments. I need more specific help. Can you write a sample code?

Comment: It is an implicit equation of x and y. How can I get x and y vectors separately?